# PHP + apache + publish base

Tags: php, apache, 1c

There is php in conjunction with apache + a published database at "localhost:8045/base1".
When I enter the address "localhost:8045/base1", php does not reach php. However, if I enter "localhost:8045", then it logs in.

I searched on the Internet and did not find a description. Can you tell me how to fix this?

httpd.conf:

```
Listen 8045
PHPIniDir "C:/SERVER/BIN/PHP"
AddHandler application/x-httpd-php .php
LoadModule php_module "C:/SERVER/BIN/PHP/php8apache2_4.dll"
DocumentRoot "c:/SERVER/DATA"
<Directory "c:/SERVER/DATA">

# 1c publication
Alias "/base1" "C:/Server/DATA/1C/"
<Directory "C:/Server/DATA/1C/">
    AllowOverride All
    Options None
    Require all granted
    SetHandler 1c-application
    ManagedApplicationDescriptor "C:/Server/DATA/1C/default.vrd"
</Directory>
```

Comment: We can't see your configuration so we have no idea if your expectation is correct or not, nor can we tell you what to change. It sounds like we need to see the relevant Apache configuration.

Comment: @ADyson I have corrected the question